# How not to display button on certain specific pages?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

New to React here, how do I not show the button on certain specific multiple pages. The pages are `/login`, `/signup`, `forgot-password`.

> App.js

```
const App = props => {
  let routes = (
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
        <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp}/>
        <Route path="/forgot-password" component={ForgotPassword}/>
    </Switch>
```

> Navbar.js

```
const Navbar = props => {
    return(
       <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
                    aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"/>
       </button>
    )
```

> What I have tried:

```
 {window.location.pathname == '/login' ? null : <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"/>
 </button>}
```

But this one works on only one page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using window.location.pathname use react-router-dom methods , props.history.location.pathname , you can write a function to check if the pathname is included , like below

```
// this function accepts two arguments , one is string and an array , array contains all the routes that need to be compared to and it will return a boolean value , which can be used to render the component

function checkIfPathExist(pathname="",checkArrayRoute=[]){

  if(checkArrayRoute.includes(pathname)){
      return true
  }
  return false
}
```

In component you can do

```
 {checkIfPathExist(window.location.pathname,['/login']) ? null : <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"/>
 </button>}
```

or

```
{checkIfPathExist(props.history.location.pathname,['/login']) ? null : <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"/>
 </button>}
```

Check this sandbox for ref

[image: Edit amazing-kirch-40vr3]

Comment: I am writing a sandbox , I will add it to the above question after I have finished

Comment: This will work for '/signup' and other pages too?

Comment: Yes , just give me 5 minutes , I will add sandbox , you can get a better understanding

Comment: I have added the sandbox, you can refer it , there in Tiger and Lion files , There I have added a function to check for condition routing  , you can do the same , check via in console if that component is getting props.history or else you can wrap it with withRouter

Comment: If it answered your question do accept the answer